# Date-Picker in xpages mobile app returns null

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I try to use the `input type="date"` in an xpages mobile html5 web-app.
The field is bound to a bean. The bean only gets null back.
If I omit the type, I got a correct `java.util.Date` back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your bean is expecting a String and does an internal conversion to Date. Have a look at your setter for this field and see whether it accepts Date as a parameter.

Edit: I was wrong. The value of the field is still text in the following format.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#form.data.date

Comment: Good hint. I'll check this tomorrow.